# Flutter Riverpod provider don't update ui, only when hot-reload

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am having issue with my implementation of Riverpod.
I have a class that's handle conversion of geo data forward and reverse geocoding. And it works great. But when I try to update the state the widget only updates when I hot-reload.

Here is my GeoService class:

```
@riverpod
GeoService geoService(_) => GeoService();

class GeoService extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _reverseResult = "";

  String get getReverse => _reverseResult;

  /// Convert address latitude and longitude.
  Future<List<dynamic>> forwardGeocoding(dynamic data) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/$data.json?access_token=${dotenv.get("MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN")}'));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        final List<dynamic> features =
            jsonResponse['features'] as List<dynamic>;
        print(features);
        return features;
      } else {
        // Handle the error, you might want to throw an exception or return an empty list
        print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
        return [];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle exceptions, such as network errors
      print('Error: $e');
      return [];
    }
  }

  /// Convert latitude and longitude to a readable address.
  Future<void> reverseGeocoding(Map<String?, Object?> data) async {
    try {
      final List<dynamic> coordinates = data['coordinates'] as List<dynamic>;
      final double latitude = coordinates[1] as double;
      final double longitude = coordinates[0] as double;

      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/$longitude,$latitude.json?access_token=${dotenv.get("MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN")}'));

      final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      final String placeName =
          decodedResponse['features'][0]['place_name'] as String;

      print(placeName);
      _reverseResult = placeName;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during reverse geocoding: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

And then in my in my mapbox_viewmodel I run my reverseGeocoding function as follows:

```
  getLngLatFromMap(ScreenCoordinate center, WidgetRef ref) async {
    final pixel = await _mapboxMap.pixelForCoordinate(
        Point(coordinates: Position(center.y, center.x)).toJson());

    var lnglat = await _mapboxMap.coordinateForPixel(pixel);

    ref.read(geoServiceProvider).reverseGeocoding(lnglat);
  }
```

And finally I in my consumerwidget for displaying the change I do the read.watch like so:

```
class ChargerLocationScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  late MapBoxViewModel viewModel = MapBoxViewModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final geoservice = ref.watch(geoServiceProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Maskvägen 54..."),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
        child: Stack(children: [
          MapWidget(
            styleUri: "",
            resourceOptions: ResourceOptions(
              accessToken: dotenv.get("MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"),
            ),
            mapOptions:
                MapOptions(pixelRatio: 10, contextMode: ContextMode.UNIQUE),
            onMapCreated: viewModel.onMapCreated,
            onStyleLoadedListener: viewModel.onStyleLoaded,
            onTapListener: viewModel.onMapTap,
            onScrollListener: (center) =>
                viewModel.getLngLatFromMap(center, ref),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: getScreenWidth(context),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              "Save Location",
                              style: theme.textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(
                                  color: theme.colorScheme.background),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 11,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                      child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/additional/currentlocation.svg",
                            color: theme.colorScheme.background,
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: Text(geoservice.getReverse))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here. I have before used Provider and that I know but this Riverpod seems nice if you know how to use it. Anyone who can share some knowledge would be nice.

Comment: This line will never rebuild: `final geoservice = ref.watch(geoServiceProvider);` because that provider is just a singleton with no internal observable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `ChangeNotifier`, if you change something and need the listeners to know that something has changed, you have to call [`notifyListeners()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/notifyListeners.html).

```dart
_reverseResult = placeName;
notifyListeners();
```

---

Additionally, your code seems to be using a code-generated provider, but the notifier is still defined manually. So in order for the code to work, either change the provider to a non-generated one:

```dart
final geoServiceProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<GeoService>((_) => GeoService());
```

or completely migrate to the [class-based syntax](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation#the-syntax).

Comment: I have changed the code and added:

class GeoService extends _$GeoService {
  String _reverseResult = "";
  String get getReverse => _reverseResult;

  @override
  GeoService build() {
    return GeoService();
  }

But still missing something bacause nothing heppens

Comment: You're supposed to return the actual value in the `build` method, not a constructor to the `ChangeNotifier` class that you made. So ideally, you should "combine" the provider and the notifier to a class-based provider. But if you just want the code to work, then you only need to add `notifyListeners()` to your current code without modifying anything else

Comment: I did ad the notifyListeners() but stil nothing happens. Since I am new to Riverpod and don't get exactly how it works, so maybe you could show me with example of the code I made.

Comment: Just found out legacy ChangeNotifier won't work with generated provider. So you might need to change the provider to a non-generated one (I edited the answer)

Comment: Now it work with the modification you suggested. But if I want to do it the new way. How does it work. I don't get the riverpod documentation. Maybe I can google some and check YouTube.

Comment: Basically make the `build` methods return the initial value (which is `""`), replace every `_reverseResult` with `state`. And then get rid of the manually defined provider and make `GeoService` extends `_$GeoService`. Annotate with `@riverpod`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256580/discussion-between-nologic-and-dhafin-rayhan).